# Loss of stabilization when using pen in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-tablet

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/ZCOKyfD.mp4) is a comparison between drawing in Photoshop with a mouse and a pen (first stroke is the mouse, second is the pen). There is a lot more stabilization with the mouse than with the pen, even though both have it at full 100%. I'm very sure it had a hell lot more smoothing just a few weeks ago. What happened?

I'm running Photoshop 24.2.1 on Windows 11 22H2 (build 22621.1413) if it matters.

I have tried restarting my computer, reinstalling the pen drivers, reinstalling an old version of the pen drivers, and reinstalling Photoshop, all to no avail. The next thing I can think of is I did a reset of the tool settings (see screenshot below) in Photoshop, but if that messed things up I don't know how to check / fix it.

[image]

Any ideas what I can do to get the stabilization on the pen back to the levels seen on the mouse?